# Print pandas dataframe to format so that it can be read in in power bi

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to print the following dictionary/pandas dataframe to a csv file, so that it can be read in in power bi.

```
df_2 = {'Status': {'AvailablePickup': 2,
'Collected': 4,
'Delivered': 55,
'Totaal aantal orders': 53,
'Packages sent out': 53,
'Packages received by customers': 51,
'result received': 220,
'Test Approved': 210,
'Test Failed': 16,
'Not yet executed': 7}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2)
df2
df2.to_csv('lolol.csv', sep=",")
```

However, I would like to get Status as header of the first column, and 'amount' as header on the  second column. Would this be possible? If so, how?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe try excel instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your base dictionary "Status" key holds all the required data as a dictionay in key-value pairs. Hence, you can derive "Status" column through `status = data['Status'].keys()` and "Amount" column through `amount = data['Status'].values()` which you can then convert to dataframe easily.

Here is the code, for quick reference:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Status': {'AvailablePickup': 2,
'Collected': 4,
'Delivered': 55,
'Totaal aantal orders': 53,
'Packages sent out': 53,
'Packages received by customers': 51,
'result received': 220,
'Test Approved': 210,
'Test Failed': 16,
'Not yet executed': 7}}

status = data['Status'].keys()
amount = data['Status'].values()

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(status, amount)), columns=['Status', 'Amount'])
print(df)

#                            Status  Amount
# 0                 AvailablePickup       2
# 1                       Collected       4
# 2                       Delivered      55
# 3            Totaal aantal orders      53
# 4               Packages sent out      53
# 5  Packages received by customers      51
# 6                 result received     220
# 7                   Test Approved     210
# 8                     Test Failed      16
# 9                Not yet executed       7

df.to_csv('final.csv')
```